# Passing two query's to a view, no GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, linq-to-entities

I have a bookings class populated by entity framework, i want to run to different queries against the table and return them both to a view. Ive read about using a class to combind them but am having trouble getting this to work...

Thanks for any help

#### Error

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ITAPP.Models.Bookings' because 'ITAPP.Models.Bookings' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

#### Class

```
namespace ITAPP.Models
{
    public class Bookings
    {
        public List<tblBooking> BookedIn { get; set; }
        public List<tblBooking> BookedOut { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Usage (for testing im using the same query for both, i will use in/out queries after)

```
var tblBookings = from d in db.tblBookings.Include(t => t.Equipment).Include(t => t.tblUser)
                    where (d.Equipment.Bookable == true ) &&
                            (d.Equipment.Deleted == false) &&
                            (d.Equipment.DecommissionDate == null || d.Equipment.DecommissionDate == dateBlank1 || d.Equipment.DecommissionDate == dateBlank2)
                    select d;
Bookings Bookings = new Bookings();
Bookings.BookedIn = tblBookings.ToList();
Bookings.BookedOut = tblBookings.ToList();

return View("Loaned", Bookings);
```

#### View

```
@model ITAPP.Models.Bookings
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    foreach (var inItem in item.BookedIn)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => inItem.tblUser.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => inItem.BookFrom)
        </td>      
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => inItem.BookTo)
        </td>  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed your question. For this error solution might be removing outer foreach loop, this one:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

as your View model is not **IEnumerable**.

So inner loop now will be

```
foreach (var inItem in Model.BookedIn)
```

Comment: yeah, added a new attempt, what can i use instead of Model to get my results, how i do access bookedin and booked out? Thanks

Comment: Your model looks correct.  Did you try removing outer loop, as I wrote in my answer? Just remove outer and change inner loop, and it should work, if view returns any data.

Comment: Welcome, glad it was useful)

Answer (score 0):

the class `Bookings` does not implement `IEnumerable` so you can't enumerate/iterate over it.

What you want to do looks like a kludge to me, but you can make it happen:

```
public class Bookings : IEnumerable<tblBooking>
{
    public List<tblBooking> BookedIn { get; set; }
    public List<tblBooking> BookedOut { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<tblBooking> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Union().GetEnumerator();
    }

    private IEnumerable<tblBooking> Union()
    {
        return BookedIn.Union(BookedOut);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Union().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```